# Spring: Field in required a bean of type that could not be found

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring, maven

Hola buenas tardes a todos.

Necesito su ayuda estoy creando un api con spring boot y al momento de querer ejecutarla me salen 2 errores uno usando el @ComponentScan en la clase principal y otro diferente sin usarlo.

Ejemplo 1: si agrego el @ComponentScan me sale el siguiente error

```
package com.cursojava.curso;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.cursojava.curso.controllers"})
public class CursoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CursoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Field userDao in com.cursojava.curso.controllers.UserController required a bean of type 'com.cursojava.curso.dao.UserDao' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.cursojava.curso.dao.UserDao' in your configuration.
```

Ejemplo 2: Cuando no agrego el @ComponentScan
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradezco mucho la ayuda que me brindan, agregare mis demás clases para cualquier duda.
Este sería mi controlador

```
package com.cursojava.curso.controllers;
import com.cursojava.curso.dao.UserDao;
import com.cursojava.curso.models.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value="users")
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        List<User> dao = userDao.getUsers();
        return dao;
    }
}
```

Mi dao es el siguiente

```
package com.cursojava.curso.dao;

import com.cursojava.curso.models.User;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserDao {
    List<User> getUsers();
}
```

Mi implementacion del dao

```
package com.cursojava.curso.dao;

import com.cursojava.curso.models.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDAOImp implements UserDao{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        String query = "FROM User";
        return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
}
```

En mi modelo tengo lo siguiente para poder hacer el pedido de los datos tal cual están en mi base de datos:

```
package com.cursojava.curso.models;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@ToString @EqualsAndHashCode
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "idUser")
    private Long idUser;

    @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Getter @Setter @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
}
```

Y mi POM he ido agregando algunas dependencias ya que no me dejaba añadir nuevos componentes al código y así lograr la ejecución del proyecto.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cursojava</groupId>
    <artifactId>curso</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>curso</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

He estado haciendo varias modificaciones al código para poder arreglar el error, pero no encuentro una solución a mi problema aún.
Pido disculpas puse tres veces el controlador, pero he agregado mi dao y la implementación del dao.

Comment: te falta agregar el codigo del UserDao, algo me dice que te falto ponerle las anotaciones de Spring.

Comment: Gracias ya he agregado mi dao a la publicación.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que tu Objeto de Acceso a Datos (DAO) tiene la anotacion de spring correspondiente el problema esta en la definicion de tu aplicacion.

La linea

```
@ComponentScan({"com.cursojava.curso.controllers"})
```

Nos indica donde debe de detectar los spring beans y dado que tu DAO esta en un paquete que no esta especificado allí (`com.cursojava.curso.dao`) tu error tiene sentido ya no se inyecta en el contenedor al inicio de la aplicación

intenta modificando tu linea de codigo a

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={
"com.cursojava.curso.controllers", "com.cursojava.curso.dao"})
```